# Are separate stainless steel and aluminum dishes really required?

Tags: halacha, minhag, halacha-theory, meat-and-milk

I can understand the need for separate cast iron dishes and raw pottery dishes for meat and dairy, but is stainless steel and aluminum really required according to *halakha*?

Pottery (klei heres) is definitely porous and absorbs, and Cast Iron is also very pourous - as well as "seasoned" with oils or fats. But if the worry is about *ta`am* (taste) or a *mashehu* of *mamashuth* becoming mixed in, then I do not see a problem as stainless steel should be treated like glass in this regard. Once it is washed it does not seem to be a problem.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but I read the other "answers" and they answered nothing. The information was anecdotal and had no sources. I got more out of the pilpul between those who "answered" and DoubleAA. Can someone answer this for real, please?

Comment: try giving a bounty